# Radius of convergence of a power series solution to a differential equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

If I had a power series given by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ and it was the solution to a differential equation, how would I go about finding the radius of convergence of said power series? TIA

Comment: The same way you would find the radius of convergence of any power series.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a linear DE and it can be written

$$y^{(n)} + p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)} + \cdot +p_0(x)y = g(x)$$,

then you can find all the singularities in all the coefficient functions $p_k(t)$.  The distance from $0$ to the nearest singularity is the radius of convergence.

Notes:  If you center the series at $x_0$, then it's the distance from $x_0$ to the nearest singularity.

You have to account for the complex singularities.  If one of your coefficients is $1/(1+x^2)$ then the radius of convergence is no more than the distance from $0$ to $i$.